# Mapsui adding map pins in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapsui

I need to add a bunch of pins on a `MapsUI` map control that uses `OpenStreetMap` tiles.

The problem is I cant find anything mentioning pins in their documentation so my question is:

Are there any pins available but have different names or i have to draw pins myself (using Geometry and Points as in some examples i found) and if so how do i keep them the same size when zooming the map ?

Maybe someone can point out where should i look in their [documentation](http://mapsui.github.io/Mapsui/api/index.html) in case I'm blind and missed it.

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the sample apps?  They use Features to draw pins on the map

Comment: yes, but they are not actually pins `var point = SphericalMercator.FromLonLat(long, lat);
            feature.Geometry = point;`  this results in a circle and i would like a Google Maps pin style(the shape at least), if i am still missing something please let me know, otherwise i think i will try to use custom icons

Comment: https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/search?q=pin&unscoped_q=pin

Comment: Thanks ! i'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you use your own bitmaps to draw as 'pins'.

Mapsui has features. A feature has a geometry which can be a point, linestring and polygon (and some others). A feature is drawn with some kind of style. What you need to do is create features with point geometry and use a symbolstyle with a bitmap as symbol.  You need to register your bitmap and use the bitmapId in the symbol. See the sample here:

https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/master/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.Common/Maps/PointsSample.cs

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! it worked very well.
For anyone that might want to do this do not forget to set the Build Action of your resource as Embedded resource otherwise your image cannot be found (right click + properties)

Comment: hello again, is there a way of using images from the drawable folders from each platform? every example i found used images inside the pcl project but i want to consider screens that have different pixel densities. An ideas something like: taking a Bitmap from ImageSource then register it ?

Comment: @kisslory Yes this is possible. You need to register a raw bitmap. Perhaps you can get the raw bitmap from an Android ImageSource. Perhaps you can load the raw bytes directly.

Answer (score 3):

Your Mapsui Map View `Mapsui.UI.Forms.MapView` has property `Pins`. You can add pins there.
You can access `MapView` View from code-behind *xaml.cs of your `MapView`.

For that, first, name your Map View in XAML Page:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns:mapsui="clr-namespace:Mapsui.UI.Forms;assembly=Mapsui.UI.Forms"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="YourProject.Pages.YourMap">
  <ContentPage.Content>
     <mapsui:MapView
        x:Name="selectMapControl"/>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then access it from C# code-behind of that Page:

```
using Mapsui.UI.Forms;

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    selectMapControl.Pins.Add(new Pin(new MapView())
    {
       Position = new Position(0, 0),
       Type = PinType.Pin,
       Label = "Zero point",
       Address = "Zero point",
    });
}
```

Hope this simplest example will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps as they give you the feature to add multiple pins of your choice.

Here is the sample code :

```
var position = new Position(Latitude, Longitude);

        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = position,
            Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("pin.png"),
            Label = "custom pin",
            Address = "custom detail info",
        };

        MyMap.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Comment: i must use OpenStreetMap as google maps is unavailable in China

Answer (score 1):

The following works on version 3.02. I've not checked it on any other version of MapSui.
First make sure your pin Bitmap is an embedded resource. You can then get the Bitmap ID like this:

```
var assembly = typeof(YourClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var image = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourSolution.YourProject.AFolder.image.png");
```

If var image returns null, then the image was not found and it's likely not an embedded resource or you got the address/name wrong.

```
var ID = BitmapRegistry.Instance.Register(image);
```

The `BitmapRegistry` method also registers the BitMap for MapSui to use later. I think if it's your first image registered it will be 0.

Then you can create a memory layer as follows:

```
MemoryLayer PointLayer = new MemoryLayer
        {
            Name = "Points",
            IsMapInfoLayer=true,
            DataSource = new MemoryProvider(GetListOfPoints()),
            Style = new SymbolStyle { BitmapId = ID, SymbolScale = 0.50, SymbolOffset = new Offset(0, bitmapHeight * 0.5) };
            
        };
```

The `DataSource` can be generated as follows (I'm just adding one feature, but you can add as many as you like):

```
private IEnumerable<IFeature> GetListOfPoints()
    {
        List<IFeature> list = new List<IFeature>();

        var feature = new Feature();
        feature.Geometry = new Point(-226787, 7155483);
        feature["name"] = "MyPoint";

        list.Add(feature);

        IEnumerable<IFeature> points = list as IEnumerable<IFeature>;
        return points;
    }
```

Then add the new MemoryLayer to your Map as follows:

```
MapControl.Map?.Layers.Add(PointLayer);
```